# git repository export and import to zip file or folder

Tags: git, import, repository, export, egit

There are some similar posts on SO related to git repository export and import, but all answers are not complete. So I am asking separate question here.

I am using EGIT in eclipse to work on git SCM.

How I can export the git repository to a zip file/folder(with all branches, tags and history)
and import the same repository back in Eclipse?

I tried,

> `git archive HEAD --format=zip >~/abc.zip` but while importing back in eclipse it's not working.

Are there any other ways for importing and exporting git repositories?

---

#### Edit

After looking at @VonC answer, I did this

```
git bundle create ~/abc.bundle --all

git bundle list-heads ~/abc.bundle
      <pre>
      refs/heads/master
      refs/remotes/origin/branch1
      refs/remotes/origin/branch1
      refs/remotes/origin/branch3
      refs/remotes/origin/master 
      refs/remotes/origin/branch4
      .....
      refs/tags/tag1
      refs/tags/tag2
      refs/tags/tag3
       ....</pre>

git clone -b master ~/abc.bundle ~/newrepo/xyz/
```

But when I tried to import this git repo in Eclipse I keep getting only the **master** branch as while cloning I used `master`. Is it possible to clone all the branches in a single command?

Answer (score 2):

Another way, which actualy does preserve the full history, is [`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) (see "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)").

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git bundle create ../repo.bundle --all
```

However, you will have to clone it again before EGit can see the exported/imported repo, because [EGit doesn't support yet bundle files as repo](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/288248/).

---

> when I tried to import this git repo in eclipse I am getting only **master** branch as while cloning I used master. Is it possible to clone all the branches in a single command?

Do a `git branch -avvv` in your cloned repo (the one cloned from the bundle).
You should see all your remote branches (`origin/xxx`).

Eclipse should then be able to list and make a new branch based on one of [those remote tracking branches](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Tracking_Branches) as in "[How do I create a proper new local and remote branch combination in EGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111655/6309)".

To restore all the branches from the bundle, see "[restore all refs from git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003661/6309)":
You need to mirror clone it.

Comment: Edited my post, added details

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I meant `git branch -avvv`, not `git br` (which is an alias of mine)

Comment: No not works. Executed `git branch -avvv` then `git branch -a` the results are:<br>`master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master`

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK then mirror clone it: that `clone --mirror` will have all the remote tracking branches in it. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12003661/6309.